# How can I cheat an XRD sample (~10 mg) from a total 1g required? How can I use for the background.

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique, x-ray-crystallography, error-analysis

How much can affect (in terms of hump) my X-ray diffraction pattern the "amorphous" glass or maybe someone can suggest me other material to compensate for the small amount of the sample.
Note: my sample is a powder.

Comment: X-ray diffraction is not a technique I have any experience with, so I'm a little unclear here. Are you saying that the sample you have is roughly a factor of 100 smaller than the ideal sample and are asking what you can try to do to still get a viable result? Do you know what sets the desired size?

Answer (score 1):

In the days when I did this sort of thing I used to use silica powder. Yes, you do get a smoothly curved background, but this is easy to seperate from the sharp diffraction lines. I could even get lines from materials adsorbed onto silica powder where the ratio of sample to silica was well below 1:100.

I'm assuming your sample is crystalline - if your sample is amorphous as well I'm afraid you have a problem.

Comment: Yes, my sample is crystalline. If I use silica powder, which in theory is amorphous but practically there is a little bit crystalline, I can obtain a poor but enough to identify the crystalline phase? Generally I know a little bit about the sample, but I want this type of analysis because it is a complementary to others (Raman, Infrared, etc.) and more "specific". Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Unless you are using a very unusual source of silica you will get **no** crystalline peaks from the silica.